# Django - Class based view - Meta tags from model don't get passed to template

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I am having an issue with my meta tags not being passed to my category.html template.

Here are my models.py

```
class Category(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
   slug = models.SlugField(max_length=255)
   image = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True, upload_to='images/')
   meta_title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
   meta_keywords = models.CharField(max_length=255)
   meta_description = models.CharField(max_length=255)

   def __str__(self):
     return self.name
```

Here are my views.py

```
class CategoryView(ListView):
   model = Post
   template_name = 'category.html'

   def get_queryset(self):
     self.category = get_object_or_404(Category, slug=self.kwargs['slug'])
     return Post.objects.filter(category=self.category)

    # def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    #     context = super(CategoryView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    #     context['category'] = self.category
    #     return context

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
      category_menu = Category.objects.values_list('slug', flat=True)
      context = super(CategoryView, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
      context['category_menu'] = category_menu
      return context
```

The commented-out code works, however, I need the second one so that I can also display categories (name from Category model) on nav template.

Here is my nav template

```
<div class="container-fluid categories-main">
   <ul class="categories list-inline mx-auto text-center">
    {% for item in category_menu %}<a href="{% url 'categories' item %}">{{ item|capfirst }} 
    {% endfor %}</a>
   </ul>
</div>
```

Here is my url.py

```
    urlpatterns = [
    path('', HomeView.as_view(), name="home"),
    path('article/<slug:slug>', ArticleDetailView.as_view(), name="article-detail"),
    path('category/<slug:slug>', CategoryView.as_view(), name="categories"),
```

and finally here is my category.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block title %}
    {{ category.meta_title }}
{% endblock %}
{% block meta_extend %}
    <meta name="description" content="{{ category.meta_description }}">
    <meta name="keywords" content="{{ category.meta_keywords }}">
    <meta property="og:description" content="{{ category.meta_description }}">
{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
```

Comment: Then why don't you simply add the line `context['category'] = self.category` to your second version of `get_context_data`? Those values aren't rendered simply because you aren't passing `category` in the context...

Comment: Thanks, @Abdul Aziz Barkat it worked! I was sure I tried that, but suppose I did not.